Timeline for new version of spring-boot-starter-web library
Understand that there has been a fix for CVE-2024-38828 as per the Spring team's article here.
Latest version 3.3.5 of spring-boot-starter-web still uses 6.1.14 spring-web which has the flagged CVE
When can we expect a new version of the spring-boot-starter-web library?

spring boot 3.3.6 should be released at 21.11 (Release calendar can be found here https://spring.io/projects#release-calendar) and it will use spring framework 6.1.15
